# Python objects memory management

Tags: python

I believe everything is an object in Python but I saw weird behaviour.

Here is a snippet from Python 3.6.5

```
a = 300
b = 300
a is b
```

Out[4]: False

```
a = 200
b = 200
a is b
```

Out[7]: True

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: In python integers are inmutable, and it is up to him to  reuse the same addresses for diferent variables. In the first case it allocates 2 numbers, in the second just one.

Comment: @Netwave that's why metatoaster mentioned the other question. In Python 2 and 3, only low-value integers from -5 to 256 are pre-allocated in the memory, other integers will be calculated at run-time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/4055552
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html